# Varying lengh of link text in menu links makes links unequal height

Tags: css

I making menu links which have varying lengths of link text. This makes some links wrap onto 2 lines and others not.

In the image below the red area is a link and so clickable, but the grey area is not. My code is the first example and I need to create the 2nd:

[image]

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#">Link 2 which has very very very long text</a>
  </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: table;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
li {
   list-style-type: none;
   display: table-cell;
   background: grey;
   width: 33%;
}
a {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Gcaem/

Answer (score 1):

This [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lk8FG/1/) works.

CSS

```
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: table;
  width: 400px;
  border: 0px solid black;
}
li {
   list-style-type: none;
   display: table-cell;
   background-color: transparent;
   margin-left: 5px;
   border: 5px solid white;
   width: 33%;
   height: 75px;
   text-align: center;
   border: 1px solid gray;
}
a {
  display: table;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a span {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
```

This is the result in firefox:

[image]

Comment: No, I need the entire red area in your example to be a clickable link.

Comment: Ive updated your answer by adding an image. This is how it looks to me in firefox, is it the same for you? The heights are the same but the red 'boxes' are not vertically aligned as they are in the image of what im trying to achive.

Comment: I use IE, so I'm not sure about FF.

Comment: I just checked it in FF and if you remove the vertical-align in the a span css it looks ok

Comment: Ive removed the vertical-align and changed the ul width to be 50%. At small widths when the long text wraps to be over 75px tall then it becomes taller than the other links in firefox. However they stay the same height (working as i want) in chrome http://jsfiddle.net/Lk8FG/9/

Comment: Good deal. I'm going to play with this some more today - It's an interesting concept of putting a span in an anchor - I'll learn more, and if I come up with a better solution, I'll post it.

Comment: Just a thought. The problem is putting a block element in an anchor tag. You might consider using all divs, then just jQuery to link a click to a page.

Comment: I cant (and really shouldn't) use javascript to replace links.